# libgdx android and ios

Tags: java, android, ios, libgdx

After finishing my game in my core project, is there a specific thing that I need to do in order to run it on IOS and Android?
I ask because when I try to run the App in the Android emulator I get:
"unfortunately game has stopped"
In the console I get:

```
ActivityManager: WARNING: linker: libdvm.so has text relocations. This is wasting memory and is a security risk. Please fix.
```

And in the logCat:

```
11-06 16:05:57.479: D/dalvikvm(1805): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.mygdx.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb2fdf1d8
11-06 16:05:57.479: D/dalvikvm(1805): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.mygdx.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb2fdf1d8
11-06 16:05:57.479: D/dalvikvm(1805): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.mygdx.game.android-1/libgdx.so 0xb2fdf1d8, skipping init
11-06 16:05:57.479: D/AndroidRuntime(1805): Shutting down VM
11-06 16:05:57.479: W/dalvikvm(1805): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2d27b20)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): Process: com.mygdx.game.android, PID: 1805
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mygdx.game.android/com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher}: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805): Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.createGLSurfaceView(AndroidGraphics.java:121)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:101)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.<init>(AndroidGraphics.java:94)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.init(AndroidApplication.java:130)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication.initialize(AndroidApplication.java:96)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at com.mygdx.game.android.AndroidLauncher.onCreate(AndroidLauncher.java:16)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-06 16:05:57.479: E/AndroidRuntime(1805):     ... 11 more
```

I followed the Zombie Bird tutorial and only thing I did different was when adding the Tween Engine Library. Since In contrast to the ZB project, mine works with Gradle and I  have an extra project folder (the ZB tutorial put the Tween Engine Library in the core project, I believe) that was created when I created my game project, I added the Tween Engine into that extra folder and followed that guide https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Universal-Tween-Engine to make it work.
Well... The game works fine when I open it with the desktop luncher, but that's it.
Can someone help understand how can I make it work with the Android emulator, and if there is something that I need to do for it to work on Ios as well?

P.S I don't have mac so I won't be able to check the game on iPhone emulator - but still hope for good.

EDIT: I managed to run the game on my device, but how can I fix it so everything will be at the right place on every device? For example to what I mean, one of my objects is a few pixels from where it is in the desktop luncher or my brother device...

Comment: Libgdx requires OpenGL ES 2.0, which the emulator doesn't support. Are you running on a real device?

Comment: Haven't tried. But how come I managed to run the Zombie Bird full game on the Android emulator?

Comment: I don't know which Zombie Bird game you're talking about. It could be written with something other than libgdx, or it could be written with an old version of Libgdx that didn't require OpenGL ES 2.0. Libgdx removed support for OpenGL ES 1.0 in version 1.0 back in April, and older versions did support it. If you want to test an Android version on your desktop, use an Android virtualizer like Genymotion.